# Open multiple windows on chrome start

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, popupwindow, bookmarklet, window.open

I work in a situation where the computer I use is inconsistent, and I often have never logged onto the computer I'm working on before. As such, I use chrome and launch most of the things I need using the "on startup" option.
My issue is that I have a page that I would like to open in a separate window. I've done some finagling with a javascript bookmarklet that does something similar to what I want, but it isn't perfect.

`javascript:window.open("http://google.com","_blank","foobar"); javascript:window.close();`

This will open a new window at google.com as expected, however It has a few flaws:

- The window is not fullscreen. It will always open at a smaller window size, and is horribly inconsistent on where it will show up.
- It isn't a standard window, I can't type in the address bar, add tabs, see my bookmarks bar, or use javascript.
- I honestly don't know what the second and third parameters in window.open do, the window will open in a tab instead of a window if I don't have them, but it doesn't care *what* is there.

I have attempted passing javascript commands through the window.open command, but the window refuses to do any of them.
I understand that this is the type of thing that shouldn't be decided by a webpage, and should be left to a user. But I am the user...

Answer (score 0):

I believe that most of the parameters you mentioned (fullscreen window, window size, other window features) are specified in the third argument of `window.open()`. For example:

```
window.open("http://google.com","_blank","fullscreen=yes;menubar=yes;titlebar=yes")
```

would open http://google.com in a new window (`_blank`) in fullscreen view (`fullscreen=yes;`) and render the menubar and titlebar (`menubar=yes;titlebar=yes`). A list of standard values is provided at [w3schools.com](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp) and [developer.mozilla.org](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open)

Comment: Nope, I looked up the full list of those parameters and tried them all, none of them had any effect on the opened window. I think it has something to do with it being defined as a popup and not a normal window.